# Is there a way of element-wise filtering a pandas groupby result?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
idx val1
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
```

I would like to do the following:

Return all the values from val1 column that have the value greater than the mean of the group (group returned by groupby)

E.g. 
Group 1(with idx = 1) has mean = 2, and the second group has mean = 5. So, i would like to get the following: 2,3 for group 1 (2 >= 2, 3>= 2), and 5,6 for group 2.

I tried the following:

```
df.groupby('idx').filter(lambda x: x['val'] >= np.mean(x['val1']))
```

Is there a way to do this by using a single groupby and a single filter method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here [`filtration`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#filtration) is used for remove all value of groups by some scalar, e.g. `2`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('idx').filter(lambda x: x['val1'].mean() > 2)
print (df1)
   idx  val1
3    2     4
4    2     5
5    2     6
```

But if want remove rows by `mean` per groups, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` for return `Series` with same size like original `df` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df['val1'] >= df.groupby('idx')['val1'].transform('mean')]
print (df2)
   idx  val1
1    1     2
2    1     3
4    2     5
5    2     6
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby('idx')['val1'].transform('mean'))
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    5
4    5
5    5
Name: val1, dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (df['val1'] >= df.groupby('idx')['val1'].transform('mean'))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
Name: val1, dtype: bool
```